# Draw Custom Buttons on Windows Vista/7 Aero Titlebar

Tags: c#, vb.net, winapi, windows-vista, titlebar

I found this question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106912/how-to-draw-custom-button-in-window-titlebar-with-windows-forms). Basically, the user wanted to draw custom buttons on the titlebar.

I tried the code and realised it works in vista/7 only when Aero is disabled. My question is, is there any way to draw custom buttons on the titlebar  **while** aero is enabled?

Also, is there any way of reading information from the current theme so I can style my buttons to match the already existing ones.

---

**Update**

Here is a screenshot from my computer demonstrating the above concept. I got the additional titlebar buttons after installing DisplayFusion.
[image: Notepad2 showing additional buttons.]

And I know DisplayFusion is a .NET program because it opens in .NET Reflector. The down side is that the program is obfuscated. Not like I wanted to decompile the program or anything; I just want to add a button to my titlebar to do something else (like minimise to the system tray for instance).
Below is the screenshot, proving the program is a .NET app.
[image: .NET Reflector showing DisplayFusion]

Comment: Forget about this, it just doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I know it is possible because there's this multi monitor app called **Display Fusion** that does just that. I know it's a .NET app because I looked at it with Lutz Roeder's .NET Reflector.

Answer (score 6):

I did some research into this as I implemented this too in my own multi-monitor solution. The way DisplayFusion and TeamViewer implemented this is overlaying a custom form over the desired window containing the buttons. You can use Spy++ to confirm this.

This is the general idea:

1. Write a DLL hook for getting notified when a window is created, removed, activated, repositioned or resized.
2. Make a transparant form using transparancy key or using this [alpha-PNG and GDI+ solution](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29184/A-lovely-goldfish-desktop-pet-using-alpha-PNG-and) and simulate the button(s) by painting it your own.
3. On window creation/removal you show/hide your titlebarbutton form for the desired window(s).
4. On window resize/reposition messages you realign your titlebarbutton form.
5. On window activation you set the Z position of the window so that it is on top of the desired window.

Getting and setting the Z position through the `GetWindow` and `SetWindowPos` API's.
Be aware that the DLL must be written in a native language. However you van use something like this to work around that problem:
[Using Window Messages to Implement Global System Hooks in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18638/Using-Window-Messages-to-Implement-Global-System-H)

And here is my result:

[image]

Comment: Your solution looks promising. I figured how to create the transparent form and detect opening, moving and closing of windows. What I'd like to know is how you create the blank themed buttons so I can paint my own. If possible, can you upload your solution?

Comment: Can you please post some code to show how you created the title bar buttons in the screenshot?

Comment: @Jelle Vergeer    Please consider to add a link for the source code of the "result", I need this solution... +1

Comment: I will make an article on CodeProject how this fits together but it could take some time as I don't have much spare time now..

Answer (score 4):

As long as you're willing to redraw the entire title-bar contents, then you can use the DWM API's DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea method, which involves setting your window to have no titlebar, allowing the DWM to draw its glass into your usable area to create a new space that looks like the titlebar but is in fact in your client area, so that you can draw buttons onto it.

The downside of this method is that you'll have to make the standard buttons if you want them.  Minimize, Maximize and Close are no problem to recreate (though you'll find that the maximize button is a togglebutton with appearance based on the state), but you might find you have issue with recreating the top-left corner button.  You'll also have to redraw your title, of course, but I can't imagine you'll have any issue with that.

As for reading the current theme's data back to restyle your buttons as theirs, I'm sorry but I don't know anything about that.  My suggestion would be to use transparency when building your buttons onto the titlebar, and to use translucent glow-effects, etcetera.  That way you'll be able to retain the glass background, and simply modify its appearance by overlaying a translucent colour.  Also, if you do it this way, then the shifting specular highlights on the glass will move naturally, whereas if you simply got their theme colours you'd find either that you didn't get access to their reflections or that they recreated afresh within the space of your buttons.  Just my two cents, of course - if you can find a way to do your theme colours etcetera, by all means.

There's one caveat to this though - there's another StackOverflow thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666979/net-framework-4-0-and-drawing-on-aero-glass-issue/4656182#4656182) which is describing an issue with the DWM API DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea method, so if I were you, I'd read through that before trying this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, system hooks are the direct approach for getting information on changed window positions and [Jelle's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/426160/jelle-vergeer) proposal with transparent form is very good. But you can use a less invasive method to get information on Desktop windows by using user32.dll

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool GetWindowRect(HandleRef hWnd, out RECT lpRect);
```

The window handles you can get using EnumDesktopWindows

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "EnumDesktopWindows", 
ExactSpelling = false, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool EnumDesktopWindows(IntPtr hDesktop, EnumDelegate lpEnumCallbackFunction, IntPtr lParam);
```

An example for this you can get from the thread [getting-a-list-of-all-applications-in-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207487/getting-a-list-of-all-applications-in-c-sharp)